# aiohttp: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'url' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, aiohttp

This error has had me scratching my head all night long. This is part of my script, and the most problematic one.

```
async def main():
    
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                for url in pepsi:
                    bottle.append((url, response.status))
    
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

It outputs the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'url' referenced before assignment
```

What does this error exactly mean, and how can I fix it? The loop works just fine without `async`, so why does utilizing `async` make this error appear?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what the error message says. Have a look at the annotations:

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
                               ^^^ `url` is used here
            for url in pepsi:
                ^^^ `url` is assigned for the first time here
                bottle.append((url, response.status))
```

Comment: I made `async with session.get(url) as response:` and `for url in pepsi:` switch places, but then I got a different error saying DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop. So confusing! Thank you for your help, Alex, I really appreciate it.